# Modelling database with restriction on columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to model the following with a MySQL database:

A *File* can either go into a *Box*, or can go immediately into a *Location*.

A *Box* can have many *Files* and will then be immediately placed into a *Location*.

*Locations* can have many *Files* or *Boxes*.

My Initial thoughts were to have two Foreign Keys on the *File* table to *Location* and *Box*, and then implement some kind of constraint that prevents both from being populated, however, I was hoping that there would be a neater way to do this?

Comment: try first if no success then ask

Comment: Present in a tabular form and your expected output. It's almost impossible to comprehend how your table/database structure looks like by reading a paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation, you database model should be like below (UML-Notation):

[image]

1. Add `Location_id` as F.K to `Box` and make a foreign key constraint with not null.
2. Add `Location_id` as F.K to `File` and make a foreign key constraint  with nullable.
3. Add `Box_id` as F.K to `File` and make a foreign key constraint  with nullable.

To check that **only one** of `Location_id` and `Box_id` in `File` can be filled, you should add **Check constraint** like below.

```
CHECK (((Location_id IS NOT NULL) AND (Box_id IS NULL)) OR ((Location_id IS NULL) AND (Box_id IS NOT NULL)))
```

But, in MySQL you should control this constraint by Triggers. (see very similar example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/two-nullable-columns-one-required-to-have-value) - not exactly the same, need a little modification)